# iPad view controller loading blank on simulator, fine on ipad and simulator < 5.0

Tags: ios5, xib, nib, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I've got an iPad app that I've been developing and testing against iOS 4.2. When I started testing on iOS 5.0, a lot of things have started working strangely.

The app starts up with a UINavigationController housing a home view screen, where the user can choose from some options before loading up the rest of the app. When the user selects the launch button, a new UIViewController is set up with the given options and then I swap the root view controller inside the navigation controller using setViewControllers:animated:

This view has a nib template that loads and then proceeds to set up other views built both programmatically and loaded from other nib subviews.  On the iPad (4.0-5.0) and the simulator (<5.0) this all works great.  However, on the 5.0 simulator, when I do this view swapping to go to the main app view controller, all I get is a big blank (white) screen.  A view gets loaded, but it doesn't contain any of the subviews in the nib (which are tied to attributes of the file owner).  The file owner is set to the view controller, the top-level view is set to the file owner 'view'.  As I said, everything works everywhere but in the 5.0 simulator.

I've tried changing my init method on the view controller (originally using initWithNibName:, now just using init) and again, it works everywhere else, but not on sim5.0.

I also tried loading and swapping another view controller in it's place to make sure it wasn't a problem with setViewControllers:, but everything worked fine.

I've tried cleaning the project and physically removing the build.  Nothing seems to make any difference.  Anyone have any idea how to fix this?